# Titanium, calling a function in one JS file from another JS file

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

so i have been trying for many hours a day now for the past 3 days.i researched this to death but still cannot get it.

Goal:

-file1.js has a buttion that when pressed will call method Main_Menu in file2.js and will open a new window created by that method, or function.

failed attempts:

-i have tried Ti.include but always getting a, cant find file error, i have tried changing string to every possible path.

-var file = require(path) but can not use the method inside the file, for example file.Main_Meue, does not work

I have also tried many other things that do not come to mind but if anyone has any advice or you need more information just ask. PLEASE HELP, AND THANKYOU

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question. `file1.js` has a button. When you click the button, a new window is created using `file2.js`? Simply put `Main_Menu();` at the end of `file2.js` and when the window is created, it will call that function

Comment: yes but main_menu(){ has a create window code }. so the code for the newly opened window is in file2.js, same as the method

Comment: calling main_menu in file 2 is unnecessary. You create the window from file1. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 2):

**second answer**

Create the second window like so:

```
//file1.js
button.addEventListener('click', function()
{
  var secondWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url:'file2.js'
  });
  secondWindow.open();
});
```

`file1.js` creates a new window using `file2.js` via the `url` parameter. `file2.js` is now your new window after calling `secondWindow.open()`

**First answer**

Based off the title of this topic, you can use the `fireEvent` method. For example:

file1.js

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('customEventName', function()
{
  Ti.API.info('function fired from file2.js');
});
```

file2.js

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('customEventName');
```

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Proxy-method-fireEvent

Comment: were does the code go for what i want it to do? i want the code to come from file2

Comment: is there any way to go about it,like in java, where i can just call it in file1, where i can make an object, or something similar, of file2 and do, object_Of_File2.Main_Menu()?

Comment: as to your second answer i have tried this as well and get the same error, "cant find file". where both files are in the same directory.

Comment: Well, you need to make sure file1 is relative to file2 otherwise yes, you'll get that error. I don't know your folder structure

Comment: using the url way how would file2 need to be, for example do i just make a new window variable?

Comment: `file2.js` just needs be located relatively to `file1.js`. The new window variable is `var secondWindow` and `secondWindow` points to `file2.js` through the `url` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

file1.js

```
var toBeExported ={
a : function(){
    //your code goes here 
  }
};
exports.a = toBeExported.a
```

file2.js

```
 var b = require ('file1');
//you can use all the functions that is exported from file1 here.
//you have to create a lib folder or place the file1.js in the existing lib folder for the export/require to work.
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

this might be a problem of code structure. Basically you have three good way to doing this depending on which version you are using (actually on which version you started your project :

- before 2.x : the best way was call the tweetanium architecture : www.shanestillwell.com/index.php/2012/03/29/mvc-for-appcelerator-titanium-understanding-tweetanium/
- for 2.x : you can use the CommonJS structure : https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium
- for 3.x : you should take a look at the [Alloy.Globals](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Best_Practices_and_Recommendations) which is the almost the same than tweetanium

Hope it helps.